# Email Studio: Hyperlink containing parameters breaks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I have a bunch of hyperlinks in my email template. The only difference between them is the parameter I need to pass. Here is how I have added the link:

`<a href="%%=v(@linkPart1)=%%&%%=v(@parameterName)=%%=1>Click here</a>`

When I click on the link from a test send, it shows `%%=v(@linkPart1)=%%&%%=v(@parameterName)=%%=1` in the parameter. I tried assigning the whole link to a variable and referred it in the `<a>` tag. The result is the same. Could you guys help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
%%[

Set @linkPart1 = "http://yourlink.com"
set @parameterName = [set where your parameter comes from]
set @url = concat(@linkPart1,"&",@parameterName)

]%%

Click <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%">here</a>.
```

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now.